# Git uncommited changes not commitable

Tags: git

I have a weird file after the last pull which is marked as not committed and I cannot commit it. It seems this file was renamed to `ContactNameFilter.ts -> contactNameFilter.ts` on remote.

```
$ git status

On branch <<...>>
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/<<...>>'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/scripts/filters/ContactNameFilter.ts

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git commit -a

On branch <<...>>
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/<<...>>'.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   app/scripts/filters/ContactNameFilter.ts

no changes added to commit

$ git add -A
$ git commit

On branch <<...>>
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/<<...>>'.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   app/scripts/filters/ContactNameFilter.ts

no changes added to commit
```

How is that possible and what to do with it?

Diff:

```
-  export var ContactNameFilter: Function = function(): Function {
+  export var contactNameFilter: Function = function(): Function {
```

Comment: what is the difference? put the output of  `git diff` in the question. It's probably line-endings.

Comment: @AD7six added, simply the variable name change

Comment: Try adding the specific file to staging and let us know what message you get.

Comment: @Makoto the same output like for `git add -A`

Comment: hm, this file was also renamed. Maybe this helps

Comment: How did you rename it? A change of case? Git is kinda weird when it comes to that.

Comment: try to pull first, afterwards add and commit your changes.

Comment: @TobiasWeichart I have already tried 2 times :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the file explicitely, and then adding it again explicitely:

```
git rm --cached app/scripts/filters/ContactNameFilter.ts
git add app/scripts/filters/ContactNameFilter.ts
```

This should work even if the file system makes problems because of case insensitivity.

Comment: I have done the first step only and made a commit, it works now! Thank you Sir